# Smart and Variable time step Micro-cap 12

Tags: transient, software

I need to perform a transient analysis with the Micro-Cap software that gives me information about what happens in microseconds but also in hundreds of seconds.

Currently, I am doing several analyses by varying the "maximum run time" and the "maximum time step" because otherwise, I get low resolution at low times or huge outputs (10^8 points).

I was wondering if there was a way to do everything with a single simulation by telling the program to perform the analysis on pre-determined times or make a certain number of points per decade. For example, 1000 points between 1 us and 10 us, 1000 between 10 us and 100 us, and so on.

In the example in the picture I used a very simple circuit as an example composed of a small capacitor (100 nF) and an enormous inductor (50 H). The first one charges in the first microseconds, the second in the order of seconds.

I report the voltages: the blue curve is the generator that goes from 0 V to 5 V, the green curve is the potential at the capacitor terminals, and the red one is the potential at the inductor terminals.

To make a single simulation with a resolution of 1 ns up to 50 s, 5*10^10 points would be needed. So I ended up doing two separate simulations.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell the program to use small time steps for small times and larger time steps for larger times (something like variable time step), in order to have a manageable total number of points but without losing information in the initial phase.

[image: Transient]

Answer (score 2):

I found how to do it, maybe it can be useful to someone: you have to use the .TR function in the text tab (below) of the project.

From the manual:

> .TR  [s2 t2...sn-1 tn-1 sn tn]
>
> Example: .TR 1n 100n .1n 200n 10n 1u
>
> Description: The .TR statement lets you set the maximum time step during different parts of transient analysis. In the above example the time step is limited to 1n from tmin to 100n. Between 100ns and 200ns it is limited to .1n. Between 200ns and 1us it is limited to 10n.